# Are commenters notified when the original post is edited?

Tags: support, comment, editing, notifications

I wanted to know if commenters receive notifications when the original post they commented on, has been edited. I've received some editing suggestions through comments for one of my previously asked questions and I don't know if the person who suggested the edits has been notified of the change or should I reply to his comment to notify him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope! The people who comment to a post are *not* made aware by default that a post has been edited. The post owner, however, is given a little blue notification in their global inbox.

If you'd like to let commentors know that a post has been edited, you would need to @-alert them in comments manually. Sorry!